# set Jquery spinner min value dynamically

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, variables

I have a jquery spinner that sets a numeric value for between 1 and 1000 for branches on a system i am working on

i need to make the min value whatever a user has set for their branch value

I.E if they have 4 branches min would be 4 if they have 7 it would be 7 etc

this is running through .net c#

this is the spinner code

```
  $("#tbBranchesVR").spinner({ min: 1, max: 1000, step: 1, stop: function () { IncreaseUser(); } });
```

i have tried getting the value of branches from c# set as a asp:hiddenfield using the following code

```
var iBranchnow = parseInt($("#CurrentBranchCount").val());
alert(iBranchnow);
$("#tbBranchesVR").spinner({ min: " + iBranchnow +", max: 1000, step: 1, stop: function () { IncreaseUser(); } });
```

this alerts with the correct value but still allows me to get below the value returned

anyone got any pointers

thanks

Comment: Please post a link to the spinner. Or better, create a [mcve] using  the snippet editor and a CDN

Comment: Have you tried it without wrapping your variable in quotes? So replace `min: " + iBranchnow +",` with `min: iBranchnow,`. I believe wrapping it in quotes is making it a string and causing the error.

Comment: `" + iBranchnow +"` is invalid unless the whole statement is in quotes  - Also no need for the function () :  `$("#tbBranchesVR").spinner({ min:iBranchnow  max: 1000, step: 1, stop: IncreaseUser });`